# Is it possible to use HAproxy in this scenario?

Tags: haproxy

I have an Apache based server running a number of sites along with the Virtualmin admin tool. I'd like to run HAproxy to direct one domain to a specific port (a Docker container) and everything else as usual (port 80) as there are several sites on this server.

Is this possible? Anyone got an example config I can work off please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but probably overkill for a single server.  You can just create a ProxyPass directive in Apache for that domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName redirectedsite.example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.0.2.123:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.0.2.123:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

HAProxy is designed as a fast load balancer for redundant websites behind it. I suppose that it can be used as a proxy/redirection tool for multiple single sites, but why?  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks. I am installing Discourse in the Docker container and read that I should avoid mod_proxy/Apache completely https://meta.discourse.org/t/run-discourse-with-or-alongside-existing-apache-sites/19514/12

Comment: Ah, in that case, then go for it.  I'd suggest `nginx` over HAproxy for this instance though, for the same reasons.

Comment: I already have Apache on this server - can nginx coexist with it?

Comment: Sure, they just can't use the same port.  Make Apache port 8081 or something, and proxy everything through nginx

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to stick with HAproxy as the server is running Virtualimin and it doesn't play nice with both Apache and Nginx from what I've read. Thanks for your help :-)